# Can't play media from Assets on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In one of my Activities I want to show a .gif image(load it from assets) and play a music file. It is really interesting that if I remove the code which loads the gif, the music gets played, but if I want to load and show the gif, the music doesn't play! Why?

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/h.gif");
web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
web.setInitialScale(getScale());
AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;

try {
    afd = getAssets().openFd("background.mp3");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setDataSource(
        afd.getFileDescriptor(),
        afd.getStartOffset(),
        afd.getLength());

    player.prepare();

    player.start();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling this exactly? Any error shown in logcat?

Comment: So you are sure using loadUrl() getting the h.gif works ? Try and place the image-code below your try-catch and check if your music plays.